# savedStateHandle not restore data from livedata

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata

I have a custom dialog fragment with 1 button. I have 1 case when this button do nothing.
When user clicks button, I call this method to save data from dialog:

```
fun <T : Any> Fragment.setNavigationResult(
    result: T, key: String,
    navController: NavController = findNavController()
) {
    navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, result)
}
```

and I have function in Fragment(onViewCreated) to listen result from dialog like this:

```
inline fun <T : Any> Fragment.registerForNavigationResult(
    key: String,
    crossinline resultEvent: (T) -> Unit
) {
    findNavController()
        .currentBackStackEntry
        ?.savedStateHandle
        ?.getLiveData<T>(key)
        ?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            resultEvent.invoke(it)
        }
}
```

but it is not called.
Case 1: User see this dialog, lock his screen on several minutes, then open app again and button doesn`t work. i don`t receive data in livedata from savedStateHandle. If user doesn`t lock screen, everything works fine.
Mayby anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: Your code will only work if the dialog is a`<dialog` navigation destination.

Comment: my dialog in the <dialog> in graph